# Precision reference voltage: buffering with OpAmp and BJT

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, voltage-reference

I'm designing a reference voltage generator for the analog section of a circuit. Two voltages as needed:

- Vref = 3 V for ADC
- Vref/2 = 1.5 V for signal conditioning circuits (with a load of about 40mA)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0OpNP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 3 V precision reference is already available, and I need an hint to generate a precision 1.5 V reference with a load of about 40 mA. In the schematic above, were are possible error sources?
I can identify:

- divider resistors tolerances
- input current of OpAmp "+" pin
- OpAmp offset
- what else?
  I guess that BJT is in the high-gain loop of the OpAmp, so its finite gain and drifts should be automatically compensed. What do you think about?

Comment: Is noise an important consideration? What's the bandwidth under consideration?

Comment: @jonk The bandwidth is DC - 50kHz. You are right, I was missing thermal noise of resistors and voltage/current noise of OpAmp + BJT noise.

Comment: How much does the 40 mA load current vary in value?

Comment: Flicker (1/f) noise might be an important consideration; there are amplifiers that do not suffer from it.

Comment: @PeterSmith *there are amplifiers that do not suffer from it* Are you sure? Where can I buy those? As far as I know, all amplifiers introduce flicker noise. It might be low / insignificant but never **zero**.

Comment: What is the Vcc? Do a calculation on the maximum current through Q1. How much power will Q1 then dissipate? Is that below its maximum? Will a heatsink be needed? Is the opamp's **DC offset** relevant? You're using 1% resistors, OK but you talk about **precision**, how much precision are we talking about? 1% (since you use 1% resistors). How accurate does your 1.5 V need to be? Is trimming allowed or needed? **Precision** doesn't mean **anything** unless you give numbers. Have a look at the datasheet of a TL431 and see how they specify precision.

Comment: Link to TL431 datasheet as an example how to specify precision:  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1610597180525&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F  Also you need to add some **decoupling capacitors** in your circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka it is quite constant

Comment: If it's quite constant then why bother with the BJT - use a potential divider from Vcc to set the approximate voltage and let the op-amp output tweak that to be exactly 1.5 volts. An op-amp is good for +/- 5 mA without much hassle.

Comment: *it is quite constant* "quite constant" doesn't mean anything. Are you saying that the current is always 40.00000 mA ? A more realistic number would be: 39 mA < \$I\$ < 41 mA. Or 40 mA +/- 1.5 %. We're engineers, we don't do: "quite constant", "contanter" "fairly constant" "superduper constant"

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Vcc is 3.3V, I've checked power dissipation (<100mW). About precision: resistors are 0.1% (in this configuration the maximum error will be 0.05% on the divider ratio); this Vref/2 is used in analog circuits before 12-bit A/D conversions, so the final error should not exceed 1LSB = 0.75mV. I prefer to avoid manual trimming. I would only evaluate if there are other sources of error, for example from the BJT, that I am not able to compute.

Comment: *other sources of error, for example from the BJT* You said it is inside the loop so it does not matter? What about the input offset voltage of the opamp? Computing things is good, start by computing the lowest / highest values of components and voltages, currents and see what effect that has.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie haha, you are right. Let me say 40mA +/- 5% (rough estimate). Apart from using only a divider without buffer, what are effects of load variations in my circuit? In other words, I'm not able to compute the output impedance of that solution. I need a hint to understand how the BJT behaves in this circuit, in terms of added error to the output voltage. This is just my doubt. Can you give me an hint with that? Many thanks!

Comment: *I'm not able to compute the output impedance of that solution* Do a small signal analysis and you will know. Roughly it will be 1/gm divided by the excess loopgain if I remember correctly. I do not expect that the output impedance of the buffer is any issue. But assume I'm wrong and prove it with a proper analysis.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie ok thank you I will let you kno

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie you are correct re: flicker noise but there are chopper stabilised opamps that sidestep the problem, including a most devious one that appears completely normal except that its flicker noise is centred around 200kHz. I can never remember its name ... checks notes ... ADA4528.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie From the small-signal analysis, I found that the resulting output impedance is Zo/hfe + Vt/Ie, where Zo is the open-loop output impedance of opamp, hfe the BJT gain, Vt the BJT thermal voltage, Ie the emitter current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stay with your current topology, one important thing to note is that the absolute precision of R1 and R2 basically doesn't matter (so long as you can disregard input leakage, which - for 1k - you can; and output impedance of your reference which you have not specified). What matters is the matching ratio between the two. If they drift by 20% and 20.0001% respectively your output will still be accurate. One easy (though expensive) way to pursue this is the use of an integrated divider with defined matching such as the Vishay ACA series with absolute tolerance of 0.1% but matching tolerance of 0.05%. If you pay a lot more you can get this to 0.01%. Since your question doesn't specify a final output tolerance it's not clear whether this is called for.

Your \$I_{CE}\$ is 40mA and \$V_{CE}\$ 1.5V. The BJT at approximately those conditions (50mA, 1V) has an \$h_{FE} \ge 60\$; for less current you'll have more gain (to a point). The op-amp needs to try and feed a small base current that will not saturate the BJT - based on [figure 16](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3903-D.PDF) this will be less than 3mA. Such a low current should not see any adverse effect from the output impedance of the op-amp itself, though I'm not an expert in this area.

The one easily identifiable source of error (other than resistor tolerance) will be op-amp input offset, as you've identified. Offset trimming pins seem to have fallen out of favour so your best bet is a lasered pre-trimmed device. You say you need sub-700uV: this is fairly easy; these things go down to 100nV. The TI LM358B series has 300uV typ, and can operate on a 3V single-ended supply; or you can pay more for less offset.

Comment: Integrated divider, this is a very good idea. I need an accuracy of about 0.7mV (that is the LSB of a 12-bit converter fed by 3.0V reference). Do you see a source of uncertainty or error with the BJT?

Comment: Not really; it's in an "easy" region for the op-amp to drive. See edit.